# Pass value from AHK argument to Subroutine in VBA script

Tags: excel, vba, autohotkey

I have an .AHK script to open an excel sheet and press a keyboard shortcut to execute a macro in it. However I'd also like to pass an argument (path of a file) that I receive from the commandline to be passed as an argument to the Macro somehow. How can I do this?

Couple of important points, I'm forced to open the excel sheet using:

```
Run, file.xlsm
```

I cannot use the alternative method of creating an excel object and then using that object to open workbook and then call the macro using the same object.

My subroutine is as follows:

```
Sub Test(String path)
    Call Application.Run("EEC.SetTargetProject", path)  
End Sub
```

I noticed that I cannot assign a shortcut to invoke the subroutine if I have an argument for my subroutine. So if I remove the argument so that the subroutine `test` takes no arguments, then I'm able to assign a keyboard shortcut to it by going to Macros > Options > Shortcut key. Is there some other way I can invoke the macro from the AHK script without using an Excel object? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

In VBA use this:

```
Sub Test()
    path = InputBox("Please enter the path", "Input path")
    Call Application.Run("EEC.SetTargetProject", path)  
End Sub
```

In AHK use this:

```
WinActivate, file.xlsm
WinWaitActive, file.xlsm
Send, ^m   ;Control + M  - or any other shortcut you choose in Excel to trigger the macro
WinWaitActive, Input path
Send, %path_of_the_file_received_from_commandline%
Send, {ENTER}
```

AHK sends the keyboard shortcut that runs the macro in Excel. 
The macro opens its own inputbox. 
AHK detects the excel inputbox, inputs the path and presses enter.